# Would it be a mistake to run a monster campaign the first time I DM?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, monsters, campaign-development

I would like to run a scenario where the players have humanoid monsters as characters, such as orcs, goblins, kobolds, trolls — basically anything that doesn't have game breaking abilities.

Would it be a bad idea to try this in the first game I run? Or should I instead try to find a gamemaster who would run this?

I already have a scenario in mind, or at least the initial setup. I was going to have them be slaves of either other monsters or of some normal races, then leave it up to them as to how to escape and then let things develop from there.

Comment: I removed the second question, partly because question posts need to focus on one issue at a time, but also because “would my idea be too predictable/boring” is a question we can't answer factually here anyway. I revised the title too, to focus on facts rather than a “should”. I think this can be answered from expert knowledge rather than speculation or opinions, and the retitle might help avoid it being closed for being too opinion-based. Cheers! (And if you get the chance, perhaps take the [tour] to see more about how the site works.)

Comment: sorry about the mistakes, I have only posed a few questions with stack exchange and I'm learning how it works. I do really like how this all works @SevenSidedDie

Comment: No problem! This is the normal learning curve. Try something, interact with the regulars, learn something, repeat. :) Welcome to the site!

Comment: if I modified the question to ask something like: "would it be possible to allow monsters to be played by players from the monster manual, or if I wanted players as monsters should I only use volo's? volon's? guide to monsters that only allows one type of monster to be played?" as far as I know the volo something book has a template for players to play a monster but its only one monster type, I would allow players to costomize a humanoid monster out of the monster manual instead. @SevenSidedDie

Comment: I think that delete was premature, so I've undeleted this. (That it's been voted On Hold by a few people doesn't mean that's a final decision, and deleting it prevents anyone else who disagrees from voting against the hold. It also prevents anyone from responding to that comment.)

Comment: That version of the question (“Can I allow monster PCs from the Monster Manual, or only from Volo's Guide to Monsters?”) is more clearly a question that's not a matter of opinion, and would definitely fit on RPG.se. I don't know that it's a necessary change though, since this might yet be reopened. On the other hand, it's enough of a different question that you might consider posting it separately *anyway*, and meanwhile we can see how the hold/unhold votes go on this slightly different question about whether it's a good idea for a new DM's first campaign.

Comment: I will wait and see, id rather not start a new question if this reopens. If I need to I could edit this one. Also I was wondering if polls that are more or less opinion and not just fact based are allowed here, or if there is even a poll function? @SevenSidedDie

Comment: @M.Aykens you should really take the [tour], you get a badge if you do.

Comment: Sorry for delaying, I just did look at the tour. It is very similar to the other stack exchange sites, it has been a while since I asked just a few questions on other se sites. I suppose this here sort of breaks the rules as a discussion but its helping me learn how to do it right the next time. @daze413

Comment: The site's not designed to handle polls, and they're deemed off topic. Because we acknowledge that a Q&A Stack is fairly specialised for solving concrete problems and that makes a lot of otherwise good questions off topic, we consider it a complementary tool to RPG discussion forums rather than considering discussion forums to be the competition. We've actually put together [a list of RPG discussion forums](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) to direct people to, for asking things like polls.

Comment: Thank you for that link, I had checked out order of the stick but my email address was initially denied, they may have had problems with botters using my email provider before and I'm waiting for an admins response so I can post there without making a whole new email.